# Filtering of Scala tuple list (within a tuple) using a second list as a key

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, filter, tuples

I am experiencing troubles with filtering of Scala collections. Any help would be appreciated.

I have the following setup:

```
val groupByLetter = (A, List((2018-10-24,1.0), (2018-10-22,-2.1), (2018-10-10,5.1), (2018-11-22,2.2), (2018-11-10,24)), (B, List((2018-10-24, 1.0), (2018-10-22,-2.1), (2018-10-10,5.1), (2018-11-22,2.2), (2018-11-10,30)))

val dates = List(2018-10-24, 2018-10-22, 2018-11-10)
```

The desired outcome is this:

```
(A, List((2018-10-24,1.0), (2018-10-22,-2.1))) 
(B, List((2018-10-24,1.0), (2018-10-22,-2.1), (2018-11-10,30)))
```

I have tried the following two, and countless other:

```
val try1 = groupByLetter.filter(d => dates.contains(d._2.productIterator.foreach(s => s).toString))

val try2 = groupByLetter.filter(d => dates.contains(d._2.map(s => println(s._1)).toString))
```

Note: **dates** list are all *strings*. Also
      **groupByLetter**'s date field in the inner tuple are *DateTime* which is why I have to **.toString** them.

Looking forward to any help with my problem!
Thanks!

Comment: There's a single `}` in `groupByLetter`. What type is `groupByLetter`? Are the dates `2018-10-25` for example suppose to be a `String` or `Date`?

Comment: If `groupByLetter` is a **Map**, then you can do this: `groupByLetter.view.map { case (letter, list) => letter -> list.filter { case (date, _) => dates.contains(date.toString) } }`

Comment: Your "setup" doesn't compile. It's hard to get good results without meaningful input.

Comment: Why is `(2018-11-10,30)` included in the "desired outcome"? The `dates` list doesn't contain that date.

Comment: @jwvh, sorry wrote up the post hasty and those were typos. I edited the post to show the correct data and omit the extra curly bracket. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put in a lot of extra work trying to make sense of your question. If I didn't get it quite right then you only have yourself to blame.

```
import java.time.LocalDate

val groupByLetter :List[(String, List[(LocalDate, Double)])] =
  List(("A", List((LocalDate.parse("2018-10-24"),1.0)
                 ,(LocalDate.parse("2018-10-22"),-2.1)
                 ,(LocalDate.parse("2018-10-10"),5.1)
                 ,(LocalDate.parse("2018-11-22"),2.2)
                 ,(LocalDate.parse("2018-11-10"),24.0)))
      ,("B", List((LocalDate.parse("2018-10-24"),1.0)
                 ,(LocalDate.parse("2018-10-22"),-2.1)
                 ,(LocalDate.parse("2018-10-10"),5.1)
                 ,(LocalDate.parse("2018-11-22"),2.2)
                 ,(LocalDate.parse("2018-11-10"),30.0))))

val dates = List("2018-10-24", "2018-10-22", "2018-10-30")

val filtered = groupByLetter.map{outerTpl =>
  (outerTpl._1, outerTpl._2.filter(innerTpl => dates.contains(innerTpl._1.toString)))
}
//List((A,List((2018-10-24,1.0), (2018-10-22,-2.1)))
//   , (B,List((2018-10-24,1.0), (2018-10-22,-2.1))))
```

I notice that the `A` and `B` lists are almost exactly the same. (They *are* the same in the filtered result.) Wouldn't it make more sense to provide test data that makes it easier to tell if the results are correct?

Comment: Thank you very much. With small modifications on my part it works perfectly. I am sorry for my bad first post. I am new to Scala, and the tuple within a tuple threw me off.

Also, I realize that I did not provide much testing data, I should have. Thank you for your response jwvh. I wrote up the test data hasty, but my full data is tuple of A-Z.